# Is there a way to trace variables through a SAS program and identify all variable dependencies?

Tags: variables, sas, dependencies

I work on a large research project and our SAS program that generates an analytical dataset is about 8K lines long.  The program has been developed and tweaked for the last 20 years or so and is now a spider web of dependencies. Is it possible to trace variable dependencies through a SAS program? The main analytic program takes ~700 raw variables and transforms those into computed vars. Some of those computed vars and then used to create yet more computed vars. We end up with 476 output variables. The PIs would like me to trace variable dependencies from raw variables to all computed output variables. I’ve googled extensively and have come across SAS scaproc but that doesn’t seem to exactly do the trick, although it’s useful for tracking dataset dependencies. If anyone has tips or sample code, I'd be most appreciative. I’ve also reached out to SAS support to ask for guidance.

Comment: I am curious on the responses you will get. I have done a lot of SAS language parsing (and log parsing). I don't think this is easily done. For some of the PROCs, there can be implied calculations if a variable is numeric or character. You would need to do a PROC CONTENTs on the intermediate steps. If that doesn't matter, you would need to do language parsing and that is very, very hard. SAS can only be handled via interpretation, not just syntax. SAS has no keywords, per se. Some level of language parsing may provide you with the information. How comfortable are you with regex?

Comment: As an example, if you have VAR1 = X + Y; Is VAR1 dependent on X and Y? Yes, but the calculations can get very rough from that simple example. A PROC FREQ will look different on how it handles variables, for example. You also have %INCLUDEs when other programs are brought in.

Comment: Even more complex when you consider functions and procedures which accept arrays or variable lists. If you could write such a parser, it would likely be massively complex and still not 100% accurate.

Comment: You can't program your way out of a lack of process and documentation sadly. Manual documentation is likely the best step here, with support from SCAPROC and log parsers. Any macros included would also mess up parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all! I didn't think there was an easy solution here. We do have an absolute ton of documentation but not 20 years' worth to trace out the entire 8K line program. And of course there are %includes in there... sigh. I am comfortable with regex but think it may be best to just go the manual route here. It would be nice if SAS had a code analyzer of some sort that could spit out a list of dependencies between variables, but I understand that is a complex and difficult ask. Anyways, thanks for the feedback and help!